# awesome_nested_set and json

Tags: ruby, json, nested-sets

I have a tree of json data. This data contains a nested array of IDs. I need to convert the tree back to awesome_nested_set.

My tree looks like this:

```
{
    "menu_211"=>
    {
         "menu_135"=>
        {
            "menu_197"=>
            {
            }
        },
         "menu_144"=>
        {
        },
         "menu_208"=>
        {
        }
    },
     "menu_1"=>
    {
         "menu_80"=>
        {
            "menu_81"=>
            {
            },
             "menu_82"=>
            {
        },
         "menu_202"=>
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to convert this to what nested set needs to save the records new left and right fields?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. http://github.com/matenia/jQuery-Awesome-Nested-Set-Drag-and-Drop

Comment: I recently re-factored some of the code to make it cleaner, however it still needs a performance boost. Check out the rails 3 example app. Thanks for coming across this.